# How to display custom fields from a plugin

Tags: custom-field

I use a plugin, WooCommerce Simple Auctions. It has a list of custom fields, which I want to display their values. I got told by the support that I should use `var_dump()`, which I did, and it returned a null string. I use a child theme for this.

I want it to display in the `content-product.php` loop, which is the loop for displaying multiple products.

What I have tried:

```
<a><?php var_dump( $_auction_dates_from ); ?></a>
```

The list of custom fields (scroll down to 33):
https://wpgenie.org/woocommerce-simple-auctions/documentation/#faq

How to display the desired value?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve a post (or product) custom field, it depends on where you want to display it.

To get a single custom fields:

```
// in your product loop, 

$reserved_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_auction_reserved_price', true);

echo $reserved_price;
```

if you want to get an array of all your plugin custom fields. You must loop trough all meta for the product

```
$product_metas = get_post_meta($post->ID);
foreach($product_metas as $key=> $value){
    if(str_pos('_auction', $key) !== false){
        $metas[$key] = $value[0]; 
    }
}

var_dump($metas); // to see the array
```